# Cannot change language on external keyboard

Tags: keyboard, languages

I have a smart TV (Pilot) which runs Android 4.0.2.
I connected it to an external keyboard (through USB).
I have English and Hebrew on the keyboard.
The problem is that I cannot switch languages through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

In the Android keyboard, I can switch through the GUI in the TV, but not through the external keyboard.

What can I do?

Comment: For me on the Rii i8 the "win" + space combination worked

Answer (score 30):

What you have to do is pair your external keyboard then

1. Go to Settings -> Language & Input -> Physical Keyboard
2. Then tap on your keyboard and a dialog for choosing the keyboard layout should appear.
3. Choose the layouts you want (note that you have to select two or more to be able to switch) and then press back.

Near the bottom of the dialog a label saying "To switch, press _____ " which, in my case, is

```
CTRL + SPACE
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do note that simply pressing `Ctrl-Space` does not work out of the box. Even though the soft keyboard might have multiple languages configured, the external keyboard must have them configured separately on Android 5.0+.

Comment: On Android 11, I found this setting under "General Management", then I tapped on "Physical Keyboard" and was able to change the language to Dvorak.

Comment: @SurpriseDog oh, I did not find such a menu in my Android TV 10. Only language of virtual keyboard can be changed. USB keyboard is set to US English and it does not work with my keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

I found it switches by using Shift + Space.

Comment: The little help dialog thing said “search+space” to switch. I noticed this didn’t work, but then I would accidentally switch the layout in my normal typing. Turns out this is the shortcut that was doing that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Or

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Plug your keyboard in, go to *Setting* → *Language & Input settings* → *Keyboards and Input Methods* → *Your USB keyboard*. Change the *Language*.

If not listed, this means you have problem with your android. I have changed it that way.