# Android TV - Changing input language of physical keyboard

Tags: keyboard, languages, android-tv

Im on the new Xiaomi MI Box with Android TV (v6.0.1) and a physical keyboard attached. The layout is English and I need it to be German (since its a german keyboard...). 
Can't find any options or whatsoever to do that. Am I missing something or is there really no option for that?
Also is it somehow possible to map some more events to the mi box remote's buttons (like longpress or doubleclick on home-button for taskmanager)?

Comment: Have you looked at the answers to this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77538/cannot-change-languange-on-external-keyboard ?