# how do I add hebrew to a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: external-keyboard

I have an external bluetooth keyboard for my android and I want to add Hebrew. I searched online for help but cannot find any. No manual came with the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Adding language is very easy (just Go to: Settings -> Language & Input -> Physical Keyboard and dig there), but there is a problem with changing the language with a keyboard shortcut:
[cannot change languange on external keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77538/cannot-change-languange-on-external-keyboard)