# Romanian Layout for Physical Keyboard is absent

Tags: languages, external-keyboard, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1, text-layout

I have just picked up my Samsung Tab S2 Keyboard a couple of days ago. The tablet is amazing, but the thing is I need to type Romanian text with specific accented characters (ie ș, ă, î, ț). This is a must-have feature. Without this, I'll probably try to return the tablet.

It never crossed my mind that Android would not have Romanian Language on the physical keyboard! The virtual keyboard has it, but what I'm particularly interested in is having the physical keyboard configured with the Romanian layout. To clarify, I don't want a keyboard with Romanian characters painted on it, only the software layout to be Romanian. That is when pressing such keys [ ] ; ' they should produce such characters ă î ș ț.

Under  System -> Language & Input -> Physical Keyboard, selecting the keyboard and then "Set up keyboard layouts", Romanian is absent:

[image]

So, can I set this up?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this? https://android.stackexchange.com/a/103494/241518

> What you have to do is pair your external keyboard then
>
> Go to Settings -> Language & Input -> Physical Keyboard Then tap on
>   your keyboard and a dialog for choosing the keyboard layout should
>   appear. Choose the layouts you want (note that you have to select two
>   or more to be able to switch) and then press back. Near the bottom of
>   the dialog a label saying "To switch, press _____ " which, in my case,
>   is
>
> CTRL + SPACE Hope this helps!

I don't have a way of trying it out myself, so I don't know what languages are available for physical keyboards.

If that doesn't work, perhaps this app could help (External Keyboard Helper Pro- looks like there is also a demo version)? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper&hl=en or free demo version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo

Answer (score 1):

A a complement to the other answer that mentions External Keyboard Helper: testing the [demo version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo), this app brings a new list of physical keyboard layouts that includes Romanian.

[image]

Only one can be selected. After enabling the desired layout in that list, switch the *virtual* keyboard to External Keyboard Helper:

[image]

The [full version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper&hl=en) is worth it as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working very well:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=varzan.extraKeyboardLayouts

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/249421)