# Polish layout for physical USB keyboard in Oreo

Tags: languages, usb-on-the-go, 8.0-oreo, external-keyboard, motorola-moto-z2-play

Up until Android 8.0 / Oreo (haven't got chance to test this issue under 9.0 / Pie) there is no Polish layout for physical USB keyboard and writing Polish national letter (i.e. using Right Alt key) is not possible in Android with physical keyboard connected through USB and micro USB OTG cable.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this problem? Some option for installing missing layouts?

*Supporting, OT and philosophic question*: Is this some kind of political isolation of my country by Google / Android developers or an ostracism? I have carefully checked that there are keyboard layouts for *each and every neighboring country that surrounds Poland* -- i.e. German, Czech, Slovak, Ukrainian, Latvian, Lithuanian and Russian. But there is no for Poland.

**EDIT**: *This question is about Motorola Moto Z2 Play, which has an unmodified, stock version of Android 8.0 Oreo and such version doesn't have "Polish" physical keyboard layout. This question does not deal with devices provided by any other manufacturer, with modified Android, where "Polish" physical keyboard layout can be available.*

Answer (score 0):

edit i am using a nokia 6.1 runing a version of stock android 9 pie

i set my English UK keyboard to polish and Ukrainian layouts i was able to get Ukrainian input working by following this 
[cannot change languange on external keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77538/cannot-change-languange-on-external-keyboard)

but i could only get a few polish letters to work 
can you type in your native language with the on screen keyboard?

try going to settings and search for languages press languages and input press add language and your language should be there
then try the keyboard again

Comment: I think we don't understand each other. How could you set your keyboard "_to Polish and Ukrainian layouts_", if I clearly said that there is no Polish keyboard layout in Android 8.0 Oreo? Please, provide more details.

Comment: i tested it on my phone runing android 9.0 pie first and i just tested it in a android 8.0 oreo vm i set the languange to polish and unfortunately i can't get it work in oreo there is not that many keyboard layouts in android yet but motorola are going to release pie for your phone so that may help you in the future  https://support.motorola.com/us/en/products/cell-phones/moto-z-family/moto-z2-play/documents/MS132566

Comment: The question is, if you are running a stock Android or if your device has modified system? This question is about Motorola Moto Z2 Play, which has an unmodified, stock version of Android 8.0 Oreo and such version doesn't have "Polish" physical keyboard layout. If you have a device by any other manufacturer, with modified Android then things can be a way different. I had a Samsung J5 once and it had "Polish" physical layout even in Android 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing my application [Extra Physical Keyboard Layouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=varzan.extraKeyboardLayouts). 
It adds multiple physical keyboard layouts, including Polish (Programmers).
No extra permission needed.
No screen of its own either. It just adds layouts next to the already existing ones. You can find them under system settings.
Please let me know how it worked.

Comment: Hello Darie. I suppose you forgot to disclose [your affiliation] that you are the developer of this app. I have made the edit to reflect that.