# Changing the input language of physical keyboard on Android TV box

Tags: languages, external-keyboard, android-tv, text-input

I have an Android box TV with Android 9.0, and I would like to add a physical keyboard, but there's no option for that. When I press the "manage keyboard" option, it shows what's in the picture.

[image: screenshot]

I have a Microsoft keyboard connected with a USB adapter WiFi to the box. When I want to write in Portuguese, the physical keyboard it's in another language, but the on-screen keyboard is in Portuguese.

Comment: Have you checked similar questions here on SO like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209005)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, my Android TV screen did not show the characters I typed on an external Genius Spanish Keyboard.

I wrote to the manufacturer asking for a driver but the answer was they do not provide support for Android OS.

After a trial and error research I found that
Logitech Keyboard Plus 1.3.0 (565k)
com.logitech.keyboard.look_ten
was the solution.

This apk is a Bluetooth driver but worked with my USB wired keyboard, I only had to set the keyboard language data.