# Using Android TV v10 with external keyboard - Logitech Touch K400 Plus

Tags: android-tv

I'm really puzzled over the fact that my `logitech` keyboard mentioned above can switch between English and my native language using simple `alt` key stroke when using this keyboard directly with Samsung's `Tizen OS` system.
However, when using my streamer with `Android TV OS` - a more modern OS, things get worse and I see no option to switch between languages.

I tried using many key combinations among them `shift+space` `ctrl+space` `win_key + space` `alt`
and simply nothing works.

On the language definitions setup of my streamer I get my native language set and in Gboard keyboard settings: English and my native language.

None of these setup helps to switch between languages, I'm stuck with the interface language of my system(native) and can write in Englush just when holding `shift + some letter` or using `CAPS LOCK`, only then I get English but in Capital letters!

Please let me know if this is problem of my streamer\android TV or keyboard itself?
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: So your question is how to change the keyboard layout of your USB keyboard (even if it is a wireless keyboard it uses an own USB dongle and is thus form Android side identical to an USB keyboard). Have you checked the answers here on the site about changing the keyboard layout of an USB keyboard like https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209005/polish-layout-for-physical-usb-keyboard-in-oreo

Comment: @robert: unfortunetely answer there no relevant